# how to sum values from subquerys

Tags: mysql, subquery, sum

i need to collect some values from multiple tables and sum this values as a column to the result table.
my query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
u.ID as id, 
(
    SELECT `meta_value` as user_name FROM `wxe4_usermeta` 
    WHERE `umeta_id` = u.ID AND `meta_key` = 'nickname'
) as user_name,
(
    SELECT SUM(rounds) FROM wxe4_170 WHERE user = u.ID
) as a170_score,
(
    select IF (count(*) > 0, count(*)*66, 0) FROM wxe4_aroundtheworld WHERE user = u.ID
) as atw_score,
(
    select IF (count(*) > 0, count(*)*100, 0) FROM wxe4_X100 WHERE user = u.ID 
) as x100_score,
SUM(a170_score + atw_score + x100_score) as darts_total_thrown
FROM darts.wxe4_users as u
```

the sum throws a "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a170_score' in 'field list'" Error.

**what i get without sum:**

```
| id | user_name | a170_score | atw_score | x100_score |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | someUser  | 449        | 3102      | 200        |
```

**what i expect with sum:**

```
| id | user_name | a170_score | atw_score | x100_score | darts_total_thrown |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | someUser  | 449        | 3102      | 200        | 3751              |
```

Why cant i access these values and how to resolve this?

Comment: You should probably simply join the tables instead of using subqueries in `select`. Also, please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the new columns that way. use a subquery to use the data to calculate

```
SELECT
wxe4_usern.*,(wxe4_usern.a170_score + wxe4_usern.atw_score + wxe4_usern.x100_score) as darts_total_thrown
FROM
(SELECT 
u.ID as id, 
(
    SELECT `meta_value` as user_name FROM `wxe4_usermeta` 
    WHERE `umeta_id` = u.ID AND `meta_key` = 'nickname'
) as user_name,
(
    SELECT SUM(rounds) FROM wxe4_170 WHERE user = u.ID
) as a170_score,
(
    select IF (count(*) > 0, count(*)*66, 0) FROM wxe4_aroundtheworld WHERE user = u.ID
) as atw_score,
(
    select IF (count(*) > 0, count(*)*100, 0) FROM wxe4_X100 WHERE user = u.ID 
) as x100_score
FROM darts.wxe4_users as u) wxe4_usern
```

Comment: so you used "wxe4_usern." as "variable" and select all from the "from" querys + the sum. do i understand this right?

Comment: yes you need a alias for the subselect table, which i called wxe4_usern (for new wxe4_user) and this is used to calculate every rows darts_total_thrown

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support Summing on an Alias Column. In order to calculate the Sum you have two possible choices. The first is to use [Common Table Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) and the second is the include your sum statements with

**Common Table Expression Example**

```
WITH CTE_SUMExample() AS (ID,user_name,a170_score, atw_score, x100_score) 
(
SELECT 
u.ID as id, 
(
    SELECT `meta_value` as user_name FROM `wxe4_usermeta` 
    WHERE `umeta_id` = u.ID AND `meta_key` = 'nickname'
) as user_name,
(
    SELECT SUM(rounds) FROM wxe4_170 WHERE user = u.ID
) as a170_score,
(
    select IF (count(*) > 0, count(*)*66, 0) FROM wxe4_aroundtheworld WHERE user = u.ID
) as atw_score,
(
    select IF (count(*) > 0, count(*)*100, 0) FROM wxe4_X100 WHERE user = u.ID 
) as x100_score
FROM darts.wxe4_users as u
)
SELECT 
 SUM(a170_score + atw_score + x100_score) as darts_total_thrown
FROM
 CTE_SUMExample;
```

**Summing Example**

```
SELECT 
    u.ID as id, 
    (
     SELECT `meta_value` as user_name FROM `wxe4_usermeta` 
     WHERE `umeta_id` = u.ID AND `meta_key` = 'nickname'
    ) as user_name,
    (
     SELECT SUM(rounds) FROM wxe4_170 WHERE user = u.ID
    ) as a170_score,
    (
     select IF (count(*) > 0, count(*)*66, 0) FROM wxe4_aroundtheworld WHERE user = 
     u.ID
    ) as atw_score,
    (
     select IF (count(*) > 0, count(*)*100, 0) FROM wxe4_X100 WHERE user = u.ID 
    ) as x100_score,
    SUM(
        (
         SELECT SUM(rounds) FROM wxe4_170 WHERE user = u.ID
        )   
      +
        (
         select IF (count(*) > 0, count(*)*66, 0) FROM wxe4_aroundtheworld WHERE user 
          = 
        u.ID
        ) 
      +
        (
         select IF (count(*) > 0, count(*)*100, 0) FROM wxe4_X100 WHERE user = u.ID 
        ) 
       ) as darts_total_thrown
FROM 
    darts.wxe4_users as u
```